# Splitting string on the basis of keyword

Tags: java, regex, string, jakarta-ee, split

I have string

```
 String x="http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg***http://storyofpakistan.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Rukn-AlaminMultan.jpg***"  ;
```

I want to extract string on the basis of `***` so I should get array of size 2,
I am doing this,.

```
String[] explode=a.split("//***");
        img1=explode[0]; //`it gives java.util.regex.patternSyntaxException`
```

I also tried

```
  String[] explode=a.split("***");
            img1=explode[0]; //`it gives java.util.regex.patternSyntaxException`
```

I am ok to write my custom generic function that can search for `***` but I want to why `split()` is not working
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Pattern#quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String[] explode=a.split(Pattern.quote("***"));
```

Now you don't have to break your head on what [special character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) you need to escape. The method "*returns a **literal pattern String** for the specified String*".

(For the sake of clarification, you're getting the error because you should escape **each** `*`).

Answer (score 2):

Use regex `[*]{3}`.Try,

```
String x="htt.....
String arr[] =x.split("[*]{3}");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String str = "http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg***http://storyofpakistan.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Rukn-AlaminMultan.jpg***";
    String delim = "\\*\\*\\*";

    String[] arr= str.split(delim);

    System.out.println(arr[0]);
    System.out.println(arr[1]);

output

http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg
http://storyofpakistan.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Rukn-AlaminMultan.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape `*` using `\\`

```
String[] arr=x.split("\\*\\*\\*");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
String[] explode=a.split("\\Q***\\E");
```

`\Q` Start quoting the regex.
`\E` End quoting the regex.

Basically, between `\Q` and `\E` the metacharacter `*` will be considered as a plain character  (ie `*`) with no special meaning.

Answer (score 0):

try this code it will work you have given wrong regx pattern.
it should be inside[]

```
public static void main(String args[])
       {
           String x="http://www.allindiaflorist.com/imgs/arrangemen4.jpg***http://storyofpakistan.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Rukn-AlaminMultan.jpg***"  ;
      String[] explode=x.split("[***]");
           String img1=explode[0]; 
           System.out.println(img1);
       }
```

Comment: The resulting array won't be size of 2.